# PHP serving a large file download times out

Tags: php, download

I'm trying to use PHP to serve up a file download. I can get the file to begin downloading, but it has only ever been able to download about 280MB of a 1GB file. I'm on a shared host so this could be the issue, if it's not an issue with my code:

```
function downloadFile($file){
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        if(is_dir($file)){return false;}
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: '.sprintf("%u", filesize($file)));

        ob_clean();
        $handle = fopen($file, "rb");
        $chunksize=(sprintf("%u", (filesize($file))/1024));

        set_time_limit(0);
        while (!feof($handle)) {
            echo fgets($handle, $chunksize);
            flush();
        }
        fclose($handle);
        die;
    }else{ echo "file not found";}
    return;
}
```

Comment: When it fails do you get an error message in the error logs or a php error output at the end of the file? Because that would probably guide you towards the issue.

Comment: My error log is blank, but I think that's an issue with cpanel. I am also unable to analyze to content of the file via text editor or anything as it's an .mp4 I'm trying to download. It just says it can't open that kind of file. The only place I see an error is the downloads window which says The network connection was lost, even though my actual internet connection has been fine.

Comment: Okay, so the error logs related to the script have no recent errors or ones that are applicable to the issue

Comment: If you link directly to the file can you download it? I ask because I would assume it is the host that is dropping long hanging connections. Something that likely can't be fixed from a shared host and not an issue with php.

Comment: Yes, it seems to download fine if I do it directly. Though that's not really something I would like to do.

Comment: I mean, I'd rather not have to tell the user to right click this link and choose download file... I just want it to download automatically. And it would also be nice to not show the user where the file is located on the server.

Comment: the web host may limit the time of execution, and the memory limit for the executions of PHP scripts. that thou mayest to sight quickly if you notice that the download is cut to the same size / same interval temps.Il should review the terms of the contract with your hosting provider to ensure

Comment: It's not actually cut to the same size, it might be a time limit though so internet speed would cause the size difference